# mvn build failures : Compilation failure

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

While builing project via maven getting following error. Tried with mvn clean install command.

Project was latest cloned and no changes done still errors coming locally.

Project seems to be passed on remote hence issue from my end.

File BlockMetadata.java has no compilation issue

Tried :

->maven update but no luck.

->Referred to other articles on XmlRootElement issue which pointed to adding javax.xml.bind depedency but if project was passing on remote build issue seems to be at my end

Any pointers will be appreciated

**`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tigerstripe:tigerstripe-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile-artifacts (default-compile-artifacts) on project test_model: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:  [ERROR] /Users/amit/project/models/external-models/test_model/target/tigerstripe.gen/src/main/java/com/Scheduler/test/model/metadata/BlockMetadata.java: [ERROR]   //  [ERROR]     ^ [ERROR] The type javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files [ERROR] 1 problem (1 error) [ERROR] -> [Help 1]`**

Comment: You'd need to show more details of your project and pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was with tigerstripe. Needed to add some plugins dependencies . Resolved now